# Asymptotic expansion of $\ln\left(\frac{x+a}{x-a}\right)$ in form of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n$?

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

How can I find an expansion for $f(x)=\ln\left(\dfrac{x+a}{x-a}\right)$ in terms of powers of $x$, in the form of:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^n$$

When I try a Taylor expansion, I always end up with a very complicated (double) series in terms of $x^n$ for $n\geq0$.

Comment: Hint: $$f(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)-\ln\left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of having an answer: consider that
$$
f(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac{a}{x}\right)-\ln\left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right).
$$

Comment: Why is this community wiki ?

Comment: @mick Because this was already posted (as a comment) by another user hence (I decided that) rep points would be undue.

Comment: Such high morals :) thanks @Did